# animation between images using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I am new in FFmpeg,

I have made video from slideshow of sequential images (img001.jpg, img002.jpg, img003.jpg....). Using following commands in Ubuntu 14.04

```
 ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4
```

But now I want to put animation like fade-in, fade-out between each sequential images, I want to generate video,

can anybody help me how to make it, i have searched lots of things but could not get....

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is create intermediate mpeg's for each image and then concatenate them all into a video. For example, say you have 5 images; you would run this for each one of the images to create the intermediate mpeg's with a fade in at the beginning and a fade out at the end.

> ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5" -c:v mpeg2video -t 5 -q:v 1 image-1.mpeg

where t is the duration, or time, of each image. Once you have all of these mpeg's, you use ffmpeg's concat command to combine them all into an mp4.

> ffmpeg -y -i image-1.mpeg -i image-2.mpeg -i image-3.mpeg -i image-4.mpeg -i image-5.mpeg -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v][4:v] concat=n=5:v=1 [v]' -map '[v]' -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

This gives you the desired video and is the simplest and highest quality solution with ffmpeg. Let me know if you have any questions about how the above command works.

Comment: You can avoid making temporary intermediate files and do it all in one command as shown in [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](http://superuser.com/a/834035/110524). If you do want to use the temp file method, then I recommend using a lossless encoder such as ffv1, utvideo, libx264 w/ `-qp 0`, huffyuv, etc (mpeg2video is lossy and is limited to certain frame rates). Also, libx264 ignores `-q:v`, so that option is being ignored in your example (use `-crf` instead).